# Apache tika() returning empty string for pdf. Java

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika

I am trying to get content of documents using apache tika() function. I am able to get contents of .doc and .docx files, But it's not working on .pdf files. I didn't specified document type in code, but don't know why it's not working for .pdf files.

Here is my code:-

In extractDocument function:

```
    int indexedChars = -1;
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    int experiance=0;
    String parsedContent;
     parsedContent = tika().parseToString(new BytesStreamInput(
                Base64.decode(document.getContent().getBytes()), false), metadata, indexedChars);
    System.out.println("parsedContent "+parsedContent);
```

Here i am getting parsedContent an empty string.
here is the function from which i am calling this.

```
public Document push(Document document, String userName,HttpServletRequest req)  {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("push({})", document.getContent());
    if (document == null)
        return null;
    System.out.println("document.getContent() is "+ document.getContent()); 

    /*  
    if (document.getIndex() == null || document.getIndex().isEmpty()) {
        document.setIndex(SMDSearchProperties.INDEX_NAME);
    }
    if (document.getType() == null || document.getType().isEmpty()) {
        document.setType(SMDSearchProperties.INDEX_TYPE_DOC);
    }
     */
    getNodeClient(userName); 
    try {

        System.out.println("client is "+ userName); 
        IndexResponse response = client
                .prepareIndex(userName, document.getType(),
                        document.getId())
                .setSource(extractDocument(document)).execute()
                .actionGet();
        document.setId(response.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.warn("Can not index document {}", document.getName());
        System.out.println("Can not index document {}"+ document.getName()+" e.getMessage() "+e.getMessage());
        //throw new RestAPIException("Can not index document : "+ document.getName() + ": "+e.getMessage());
    }
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("/push()={}", document);
    return document;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure you were using the most recent version of Apache Tika?

Comment: I am using apache tika 1.5 version.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version? What happens when you upgrade to the latest one?

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution from here

[Error while parsing Binary Files... (mostly PDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489206/error-while-parsing-binary-files-mostly-pdf)

Download these 3 jar files and copy them to your lib folder and add them to project.

```
fontbox-1.5.0.jar 
jempbox-1.5.0.jar 
pdfbox-1.5.0.jar
```

Comment: Don't do that. These files are hopefully outdated. 1.8.9 is the current version.